# How to add new pairs in IEnumerable < KeyValuePair<string, int>>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a solution to this problem
Given a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` I need to add new key value pair to it

I tried to do the following:

```
myKeyValue.Add(new IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ...)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` does not contain a definition for `Add` and no accessible extension method `Add` accepting a first argument of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` could be found

Comment: `IEnumerable` is a readonly interface, you can't add anything working via it. If you need mutable `myKeyValue` change it's type or reassign the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IEnumerable` is read-only. You can't modify it. You could project to a *new* collection:

```
var newDict = oldDict.Append(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(newValue));
```

but that does not change the original collection.

If you *need* to modify the original collection (which seems dangerous if you are only given it as an `IEnunmerable`), you could *try* casting to a writable interface (like `ICollection<KeyValuePair<...>>`) and add an item, but if that cast fails (meaning the underlying object is not actually writable) there's nothing else you can do.

Answer (score -1):

`IEnumerable<T>` really does not contain method `.Add(...)`.
Add method declared in `IList<T>` interface;

Though, you can use a LINQ extension method `.Append(item)`

And here is some example code:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> myKeyValue = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

myKeyValue = myKeyValue.Append(new IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>());
```

And, if possible, looking at your question, you can try `Dictionary<string, int>` which is basically a list of KeyValuePair-s checking that a key could be presented in a list only once

Comment: It should be `myKeyValue = myKeyValue.Append(new IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>());` otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @GuruStron true, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Note that this does not modify the original collection, just points the reference to a _new_ collection.  If someone has a reference to the old list they would not see the added item.

Comment: Note that this will not change original collection. And possibly there will be type mismatch.